# ASP.net: weird url parameter when implment meta refresh on header

Tags: asp.net

I was trying to implement Rick's adding meta refresh via header on this [article](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/6841.aspx)

For some reason my url look like this

http://localhost/pickweb/(S(hp5mypqznxgquf45vzz4fi55))/Login.aspx

What is this "(S(hp5mypqznxgquf45vzz4fi55))" in my url? Even if i remove the code in Rick's blog it still have that weird parameter.

I implement Rick's code

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "4; url=profile.aspx");
```

in my Master page.

Jack

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using cookieless sessions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...I think I figure out where it come from. I think it's because my web.config have set session in InProc. Could that be the reason where that parameter come from.